# Differentiate sectors with function editor of QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I am new to QGIS.

I have a layer that, among other fields, has two with the structure below:

```
id | Class
1  | 2
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 5
5  | 6
6  | 2
7  | 3
8  | 4
```

The id column represents specific regions of a layer and class has values ranging from 1 to 7. I would like to differentiate the regions based on the value of the layer column. I am trying to do it through the function editor, but I am not able to reference the columns in the code.

How do I do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the layer in the table of contents, then go to properties->symbology and change the display settings such that each value for "class" will be shown in a unique color.

Find the symbology tab on the left side of the window that comes up when you click properties, then change the values in top box to 'categorized' and the second box to your "Class" column. [image: window view]

Comment: I didn't find symbology in properties

Comment: See edited answer